# unable to get unique values from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the unique values from two table

```
select AVP_KEY
(SELECT AVP_KEY FROM AVP_KEY WHERE AVP_KEY in(SELECT DISTINCT NEW_AVP_KEY FROM GTT_STG_ITEM_ATTR_AVP WHERE ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID IN(SELECT ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID FROM GTT_STG_ITEM_ATTR_AVP WHERE INSERT_TYPE=2
MINUS
SELECT ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID FROM GTT_STG_ITEM_ATTR_AVP WHERE INSERT_TYPE=1)))
WHERE 
 AVP_KEY NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT AVP_KEY FROM STG_IT_ATTRIBUTE PARTITION(STG_IT_ATTRIBUTE2460785) WHERE JOB_LOG_ID=2460785 AND CLIENT_ID=355);
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique values"? Set theoretic operation `MINUS` is probably not the right tool, but it depends on what you are really trying to do.

Comment: It means like SELECT AVP_KEY FROM AVP_KEY WHERE AVP_KEY in(SELECT DISTINCT NEW_AVP_KEY FROM GTT_STG_ITEM_ATTR_AVP WHERE ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID IN(SELECT ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID FROM GTT_STG_ITEM_ATTR_AVP WHERE INSERT_TYPE=2
MINUS
SELECT ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID FROM GTT_STG_ITEM_ATTR_AVP WHERE INSERT_TYPE=1)) return me 1,2,3 and SELECT DISTINCT AVP_KEY FROM STG_IT_ATTRIBUTE PARTITION(STG_IT_ATTRIBUTE2460785) WHERE JOB_LOG_ID=2460785 AND CLIENT_ID=355 return me 1,2,3,4 I need 4 as output

Comment: **Please edit your question**. Large chunks of code are too hard to read in comments

Answer (score 0):

try to modify the code with

```
SELECT distinct AVP_KEY from (SELECT AVP_KEY FROM AVP_KEY WHERE AVP_KEY IN (SELECT NEW_AVP_KEY FROM GTT_STG_ITEM_ATTR_AVP WHERE ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID IN (SELECT ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID FROM GTT_STG_ITEM_ATTR_AVP WHERE INSERT_TYPE=2 MINUS SELECT ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID FROM GTT_STG_ITEM_ATTR_AVP WHERE INSERT_TYPE=1 ) ) ) WHERE AVP_KEY NOT IN (SELECT AVP_KEY FROM STG_IT_ATTRIBUTE PARTITION(STG_IT_ATTRIBUTE2460785) WHERE JOB_LOG_ID=2460785 AND CLIENT_ID =355 );
```

========================================================================